# pd.read_sql has poor performance

Tags: postgresql, api, performance, fastapi

I'm building an API that reads data from a table in PostgresQL, perform some transformations and return it.

However, when I try to run `pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table", engine)`, it seems to take quite a few seconds.

On the contrary, when I try to read it from DBeaver, the query took less than a second to return the result.

May I get some advice to improve this? Ideally, I'm trying to make the API to return the result quicker and optimising this seems to be a good step.

Additional information: The table has around 3k records and 10 columsn.

Code:

```py
def query_data():
    items = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM items", engine)

    return items.to_list()


@app.get("/get_data")
def get_data():
    t_1 = time()
    items = query_data()
    t_2 = time()
    print("t_2 - t_1: ", round(t_3 - t_2, 0), "s")
    return items
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), provide a [mre], share code, and more info like how many records are in that table ?

Comment: Done. Reason why I didn't include code was because it was very simple :)

Comment: And stil no info on how many columns, and records, in this table.....  it really says [minimal REPRODUCIBLE problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: by the book kinda guy...and not sure if the information could actually help...but I've added anyway. If you don't have the answer, please ...

Comment: Don't snipe at people looking for basic information. I have seen many questions whose problems where down to someone screwing up  'simple'  code. The purpose of a minimal reproducible example is to get everyone on the same page and eliminate as many assumptions as possible.

Comment: What you have discovered is that: `items = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM items", engine)` ,  in other words the creation of a `DataFrame` is a non-trivial operation. It is more involve then simply returning values, it involves creating a `DataFrame` object and moving the data into it.

Comment: I think you're right. The bottom line is that it has to perform many more operations which might be the reason why it's slow. I'm looking for any suggestions from anyone who might come across it before, for at least has an idea :) thanks

Comment: Compare it to a single, raw SQL query using psycopg2 instead, and you'll see where the actual problem is (and possibly attach a debugger) - then start doing less of what is costing a lot of time - for example, if you can avoid creating dataframes, avoid that - or cache the structure somewhere pre-created.

Comment: thanks, let me try to take a look at those points